# Group By Query Builder not returning Object in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, laravel-5.8

I am having issue with a groupby function. Please i need help.
Here is my code

```
$rate = Rate::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->groupBy([function($item) {
                return $item->location;
            },
            function($item) {
                return ['currency' => $item->currency];
            },
            function($item) {
                return ['time' => $this->rateTime($item->created_at->format('H'))];
            }]
        );
```

This is the result its returning

```
"data": {
        "Lagos": {
            "GBP": {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "currency": "GBP",
                        "buy_rate": "350",
                        "sell_rate": "450",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-25 16:00:41",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-25 16:00:41"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "USD": {
                "Morning": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "buy_rate": "390",
                        "sell_rate": "450",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-25 04:04:00",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-25 04:04:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "EUR": {
                "Evening": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "buy_rate": "530",
                        "sell_rate": "545",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 18:33:30",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 18:33:30"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "NGN": {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:41:19",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:41:19"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:39:15",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:39:15"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Ghana": {
            "NGN": {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Ghana",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:38:26",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:38:26"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what i need

```
"data": {
        "Location": "Lagos",
                       {
           "Currency": "GBP" {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "currency": "GBP",
                        "buy_rate": "350",
                        "sell_rate": "450",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-25 16:00:41",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-25 16:00:41"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Currency": "USD",
                  {
                "Morning": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "buy_rate": "390",
                        "sell_rate": "450",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-25 04:04:00",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-25 04:04:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Currency": "EUR" {
                "Evening": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "buy_rate": "530",
                        "sell_rate": "545",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 18:33:30",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 18:33:30"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Currency": "NGN" {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:41:19",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:41:19"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Lagos",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:39:15",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:39:15"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Location": "Ghana" {
           "Currency": "NGN" {
                "Afternoon": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "currency": "NGN",
                        "buy_rate": "20.45",
                        "sell_rate": "32.34",
                        "location": "Ghana",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-21 16:38:26",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-21 16:38:26"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be get an object with keys and values and not only the values. Been trying diferent ways but still now getting it. I will be glad if someone could be of help to me.

Comment: You can't just with querybuilder. You need to change your results using collection functions.

Comment: Please how will i do that